# MySQL create both entities with cyclic foreign key

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to have an "Entity" and many versions of it, where one of those versions is the only one which is active/used. It is also possible that the Entity is entirely deactive. So I thought of using two tables with cyclic foreign keys like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- some extra irrelevant data commented out
  active_version_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE entityversion (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  -- some extra irrelevant data commented out
  entity_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE entity ADD FOREIGN KEY (active_version_id) REFERENCES entityversion(id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
ALTER TABLE entityversion ADD FOREIGN KEY (entity_id) REFERENCES entity(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I would like to, when creating a new active Entity, to create at the same time its first EntityVersion which will be its active_version. The problem is we don't have their ids yet. Currently, we're creating the Entity with "returning id" and using that to create the EntityVersion, also with "returning id", and then updating the active_version_id of that same Entity, so 3 separate commands like this for example:

```
INSERT INTO entity DEFAULT VALUES RETURNING id;
-- get the ID back and use it as a parameter to the next command
INSERT INTO entityversion (entity_id) VALUES (%s) RETURNING id;
-- again the same thing
UPDATE entity SET active_version_id = %s WHERE id = %s;
```

I would like to know if there is a shorter way to do this. I also accept as answer a different approach to the table schemas, if it happens to be the better choice. Thanks for the help!

Comment: re `ON DELETE SET NULL`, what's the scenario where you would delete an entityversion that is the active one?

Comment: your foreegn keys will not work, as you need to have each other at the same tome. Remove the one from entity and make a trgger

Comment: `CREATE TABLE entity` will fail due to `entityversion` not exists.

Comment: *I would like to, when creating a new Entity, to create at the same time its first EntityVersion which will be its active_version.* Formally - you may use according trigger. Really - where "*my data here*" for this autocreated row must be taken from?

Comment: @ysth if for some reason the active version is deleted, I dont want the Entity to be destroyed, thats it.

Comment: @Akina ok sorry I edited my question and used ALTER TABLE (:

Comment: @nbk could you articulate more about your "make a trigger" suggestion please?

Comment: it deüends what you want to do but t´if you strt a trans action insert the a row in events you can  directly enter entityversion  with entity_id  and LAST_INSERT_ID, stiil you ring dependency and that will cause problems

Comment: your circular foreign keys solve a problem for you; I'm not sure why people are intent on you getting rid of them

Answer (score 1):

You are implying that the entities are 1:1, in which case they may as well be in the same table.  (Make one of the NULLable if it is not to inserted until later.)

If it is 1:many (a 'latest' and many 'older' versions), then the FK only goes one way.

In either case, your "circular" FKs go away.

But to answer your question:

1. Turn off FK checks
2. CREATE both tables
3. Populate both tables
4. ALTER to add both FKs
5. Turn on FK checks.

**More**

Well, it seems that you have many:1, not 1:1.  The "History" has a column that is the "id" into the "Current" ('active') table.  No circular FKs.  Index that column so you can go the other way efficiently.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` is not practical in either direction.

The FK should go one direction, not both.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the reply. Yeah, my use case is exactly that one-entity many-versions (but not exactly latest/oldest, it is time-independent).
The FK checks are not the issue, as the active_version_id is a nullable FK, so it doesn't block anything (and in my usecase I can have an Entity without active versions indeed). I just added more details to my question, sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: @JordiReinsma - I added more.

Answer (score 1):

Create both your rows in a stored procedure, or use a before insert trigger if there is no data that *only* goes in the entityversion version table.  To deal with your cyclical id problem, in mariadb use a sequence instead of auto_increment.  In mysql, emulate a sequence with an entity_sequence table that only contains the auto_increment id.  In your stored procedure/trigger, get the sequence value (with `insert..returning id` if emulating a sequence), store entityversion using that value, then set the entityversion id to store in your entity row.

Comment: Hey ysth. Let me know if you think this is appropriate: instead of the sequence table, get in a prior SELECT the next auto_increment id from entityversion table (inside a trigger or transaction, I think it will be a transaction, as I only wanna do it when I really want to create both entity and version at the same time) and use it as parameter for the first `INSERT into entity`, removing the necessity of doing that UPDATE command. Would you recommend this? Or is there a reason to use an sequence table?

Comment: you have to create the entityversion before you can select; there isn't a safe way to read what the next auto increment id is going to be without actually creating the row, and to create the row you need the entity id.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't thinking this through enough; because of the foreign key constraints, you can't create either row first; you will have to update the entity with the active entityversion after creating both.  so a sequence or emulated sequence doesn't help at all.